# How do I access the guest virtual machines through an esxi server?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed Guest VM with default template which has some static IP address and which is not reachable from outside i.e private Network. My ultimate aim to change the IP address. How do I change the IP address of the Quest VM through Vcenter. Currently the VCenter/Vshpere client is only reachable from internet.

Example: 10.197.70.26 is my Vcenter/Vsphere, 172.16.185.2 is my Guest VM IP address which is in Portgroup: "Private Network". I need to change the IP address to 10.197.70.50 (private/public network) through command line. Note: Quest VM is not reachable from Public network

Comment: If you have access to vcenter then just open a remote console connection and login to the server that way.

Comment: @Appleoddity i am new to VMware related stuff, can you help for the steps or any doc u have, please share. Also i have to do all this in Ansible automation. 
a. Install new VM with predefined OVA template, later i have to change the IP address through automation. Thats y i am looking for any option to access the guest vm via ssh.

Comment: In vCenter, right-click the virtual machine and “Open Console.”

Comment: @Appleoddity, I am looking for an automation steps, How to Achieve this Ansible Automation. else How to change the IP address of VM host in Vcenter via SSH.